# Python Flask REST API on Windows Cherrypy

Tags: python, flask, cherrypy

I'm trying to create a python Flask REST web API. Since Flask development server is not suitable for production, I tried to use cherrypy application server.

Following is the Flask app I tried to expose via cherrypy

```
from flask import Flask,request
from flask_restful import Api,Resource, reqparse

app= Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

class Main (Resource):
    def get(self):
        return "Hello Flask"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api.add_resource(Main, "/testapp/")
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Following is the cherrypy script I have created

```
try:
from cheroot.wsgi import Server as WSGIServer, PathInfoDispatcher
except ImportError:
    from cherrypy.wsgiserver import CherryPyWSGIServer as WSGIServer, WSGIPathInfoDispatcher as PathInfoDispatcher

from stack import app

d = PathInfoDispatcher({'/': app})
server = WSGIServer(('127.0.0.1', 8080), d)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   try:
      server.start()
      print("started")
   except KeyboardInterrupt:
      server.stop()
```

I have saved this script as "run.py" in my project directory. When I run this it doesn't show any error, which made me to thin this is correct.

But unfortunately I cant access this using the url

Theoretically, url for this API should be some thing like follow
   http://127.0.0.1:8080/testapp/

But it throws 404 with the message

*"The requested URL was not found on the server.  If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again."*

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

The

```
api.add_resource(Main, "/testapp/")
```

in your file *stack.py* is not executed if the file is included from your *run.py*
as the condition

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
...
```

is not true (in the context of *stack.py*).

Moving the call to *api.add_resource(...)* to a position outside the *if-main-condition* (so it is always executed) should solve the issue.